# Why do I get compiler error CS0117 - 'class name' does not contain a definition for 'method name'

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to call a `load_words()` method from `Words` class in the `Main()` method and it's giving me this error:

> Error CS0117  'Words' does not contain a definition for 'load_words'

How do I call this function?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You need to make sure you are using the same namespace.  You may have two different classes called words and using the wrong one.  Or the upper/lower letters in the name of the class words is different so you actually have two different classes.

Comment: If it was a namespace issue the error would more likely indicate that the compiler couldn't find the class. But the error indicates that it has found the class (so the namespace is probably ok) but it can't find the method.

Answer (score 1):

-If you are using it in different **namespace** and trying to use the other namespace's dll then it wont refer this method.

-You may need to rebuild the project

-if not try create class with namespace name might resolve your problem

```
namespace.Words words = new namespace.Words(); 
words.load_words();
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler isn't telling you that it can't find the *class*, `Words`. It's telling you that it can't find the *method*.

Sometimes the method exists but you can't call it. For example, maybe it's not public. But if that were the case you would get a different error message.

So the most likely cause is a typo where you're calling the method. Verify you've got the name of the method exactly correct. It's case-sensitive. If you haven't exactly matched the name of the method then the method you're calling actually doesn't exist, which is why the compiler says the class doesn't contain that method.

Another possibility is that you've got two classes named `Words`. One is in the same namespace as your `Main` method and the other isn't. If the one with a `load_words` method is in another namespace, then the compiler is looking at the class that *doesn't* have that method.